# Classic ASP and JAVA Slider help needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic

I am using the Jssor slider and have implemented some classic asp into it in order to pull the images and some other things from an access database. It pulls the first image perfectly but will never go to the second image.

I can use the <%rs.movenext%> but if I use <% rs.movenext loop%> the page crashes.

I have been working on this for 3 days and can't seem to figure it out so any help would be extremely appreciated.

below is a copy of the code from the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--#include file="dbconnect.asp"-->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Banner Rotator Demo - Jssor Slider, Slideshow with Javascript Source Code</title>
</head>
<body style="background:#fff;">

    <style> 
        .captionOrange, .captionBlack
        {
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 20px;
            line-height: 30px;
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }
        .captionOrange
        {
            background: #EB5100;
            background-color: rgba(235, 81, 0, 0.6);
        }
        .captionBlack
        {
            font-size:16px;
            background: #000;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        }
        a.captionOrange, A.captionOrange:active, A.captionOrange:visited
        {
            color: #ffffff;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        a.captionOrange:hover
        {
            color: #eb5100;
            text-decoration: underline;
            background-color: #eeeeee;
            background-color: rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.7);
        }
        .bricon
        {
            background: url("../img/browser-icons.png");
        }
    </style>
    <!-- it works the same with all jquery version from 1.3.1 to 2.0.3 -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- use jssor.slider.mini.js (39KB) or jssor.sliderc.mini.js (31KB, with caption, no slideshow) or jssor.sliders.mini.js (26KB, no caption, no slideshow) instead for release -->
    <!-- jssor.slider.mini.js = jssor.sliderc.mini.js = jssor.sliders.mini.js = (jssor.core.js + jssor.utils.js + jssor.slider.js) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jssor.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jssor.utils.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jssor.slider.js"></script>

    <%
    strSQLQuery = "SELECT * FROM SliderImages where i_active = true"
    Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 
    rs.Open strSQLQuery, conn, 3, 3
    if not rs.eof then
    'rs.movenext
    'loop
    %>
    <div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; width: 1040px;
        height: 300px;">


        <div u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
            <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity:0.7; position: absolute; display: block;
                background-color: #000; top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
            </div>
            <div style="position: absolute; display: block; background: url('../img/loading.gif') no-repeat center center;
                top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%">
            </div>
        </div>
        <%' if rs("i_active") = "True" then %>

        <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1040px; height: 300px;
            overflow: hidden;">
            <% if rs("i_href") > " " then %>
            <div>
                <a u=image href=""><img src="/images/slider/<%=rs("i_image")%>" width="1040" height="300" /></a>
                <% if rs("i_box") = "True" then %>
                <div u=caption t="*" class="captionOrange"  style="position:absolute; left:20px; top: 30px; width:300px; height:30px;"> 
                <% =rs("b_text") %>
                </div>
                <% end if %>
            </div><% 'rs.movenext 'loop %>
            <% else %>
            <div>
                <img src="/images/slider/<%=rs("i_image")%>" width="1040" height="300" />
                 <% if rs("i_box") = "True" then %>
                <div u=caption t="*" class="captionOrange"  style="position:absolute; left:20px; top: 30px; width:300px; height:30px;"> 
                <% =rs("b_text") %>
                </div>
                <% end if %>
            </div><% rs.movenext 'loop %>

        </div>

        <style>
            /*
            .jssorn01 div           (normal)
            .jssorn01 div:hover     (normal mouseover)
            .jssorn01 .av           (active)
            .jssorn01 .av:hover     (active mouseover)
            .jssorn01 .dn           (mousedown)
            */
            .jssorn01 div, .jssorn01 div:hover, .jssorn01 .av
            {
                filter: alpha(opacity=70);
                opacity: .7;
                overflow:hidden;
                cursor: pointer;
                border: #000 1px solid;
            }
            .jssorn01 div { background-color: gray; }
            .jssorn01 div:hover, .jssorn01 .av:hover { background-color: #d3d3d3; }
            .jssorn01 .av { background-color: #fff; }
            .jssorn01 .dn, .jssorn01 .dn:hover { background-color: #555555; }
        </style>

        <div u="navigator" class="jssorn01" style="position: absolute; bottom: 16px; right: 10px;">
            <!-- navigator item prototype -->
            <div u="prototype" style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 12px; HEIGHT: 12px;"></div>
        </div>


        <style>
            /* jssor slider direction navigator skin 05 css */
            /*
            .jssord05l              (normal)
            .jssord05r              (normal)
            .jssord05l:hover        (normal mouseover)
            .jssord05r:hover        (normal mouseover)
            .jssord05ldn            (mousedown)
            .jssord05rdn            (mousedown)
            */
            .jssord05l, .jssord05r, .jssord05ldn, .jssord05rdn
            {
                position: absolute;
                cursor: pointer;
                display: block;
                background: url("../img/d17.png") no-repeat;
                overflow:hidden;
            }
            .jssord05l { background-position: -10px -40px; }
            .jssord05r { background-position: -70px -40px; }
            .jssord05l:hover { background-position: -130px -40px; }
            .jssord05r:hover { background-position: -190px -40px; }
            .jssord05ldn { background-position: -250px -40px; }
            .jssord05rdn { background-position: -310px -40px; }
        </style>

        <span u="arrowleft" class="jssord05l" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; top: 123px; left: 8px;"><img src="/images/slider/prev.png" width: "40px"; height: "40px"/>
        </span>

        <span u="arrowright" class="jssord05r" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; top: 123px; right: 8px"><img src="/images/slider/next.png" width: "40px"; height: "40px" />
        </span>

        <a style="display: none" href="">jQuery Carousel</a>
    </div>

    <% end if %>
    <% 'on error resume next %>
        <% rs.movenext %>
        <% 'loop %>
        <% end if %>
        <% 'wend %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What crashes? JavaScript error or server error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<% rs.movenext loop %>` is not valid. They are two separate commands so if on the same line they would have to be separated with a colon like this: `<% rs.movenext : loop %>`

But you don't seem to have the first part of the loop in your code. You need to put a **Do** command at the beginning of the code you want to loop for each record.

Put `<% Do Until rs.EOF %>` at the beginning of the code you want to loop and `<% Loop %>` at the end of the code you want to loop.

I'm guessing you want to change just part of the code to this:

```
<div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1040px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden;">
<% Do Until rs.EOF %>
    <% if rs("i_href") > " " then %>
        <div>
            <a u=image href=""><img src="/images/slider/<%=rs("i_image")%>" width="1040" height="300" /></a>
            <% if rs("i_box") = "True" then %>
            <div u=caption t="*" class="captionOrange"  style="position:absolute; left:20px; top: 30px; width:300px; height:30px;"> 
            <% =rs("b_text") %>
            </div>
            <% end if %>
        </div>
        <% else %>
        <div>
            <img src="/images/slider/<%=rs("i_image")%>" width="1040" height="300" />
             <% if rs("i_box") = "True" then %>
            <div u=caption t="*" class="captionOrange"  style="position:absolute; left:20px; top: 30px; width:300px; height:30px;"> 
            <% =rs("b_text") %>
            </div>
            <% end if %>
        </div>
<% end if %>
<% rs.MoveNext %>
<% Loop %>
    </div>
```

Comment: if I do that the page crashes with a 500 error. And yes I am just trying to figure out how to make it pull the next record. everything else is working fine. you can see the page at efbconline.com/slider.asp

Comment: Are you just seeing "500 internal server error"?  If you are here's how to get more helpful error messages - http://www.chestysoft.com/asp-error-messages.asp

Comment: I had another look over the code and it appears that you are missing an End If. I have updated the code in my answer. If you still get a 500 error you need to find out what line it is happening on and let us know.